# What version of apache tomcat supports java 7 features in netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, java-7

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 with apache tomcat server of version 5.5.It is not supporting java 7 features and asking to set server level to 7? how can i do that? or should i use other server?which one will u recommend?

Comment: tomcat 7 is out long before. Java 7?? As far as i know, the only feature which u can test with naked eye is Switch case with string.

Comment: Well,i was trying to connect servlet to database, and want to use joinrowset feature present in JDBC4.1.

Comment: Not to be snarky or anything, but Tomcat 5.5 was released EIGHT YEARS AGO.

Comment: Good,but my question is "What version of apache tomcat supports java 7 features in netbeans?" shall i take ur answer as 7?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tomcat 7 does work with Java 7. You can check Tomcat 7 latest changelog at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html

Note: Most of the times, it's good to start your development with latest server available (unless you have a very specific version requirements)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Tomcat version that support Java 7 currently.All the currently supported Apache Tomcat versions (5.5.x, 6.0.x and 7.0.x) are known to run correctly on Java 6.